# How do real world applications deal with IOTA snapshots?

Tags: snapshot

IOTA is constantly mentioned in the news about new cooperations between IOTA and other business partners. But how do applications such as the over-the-air proof-of-concept of IOTA and VW handle snapshots? What problems do they have? And if they don't have problems with snapshots, why not?

For me, the big advantage of a structure like the tangles is that no information is lost. If you delete them now, won't that torpedo the basic concept?

Comment: To be clear: I know why IOTA snapshots are done, but i don't know how applications, which rely on data integrity, deal with them.